# resources on numpy operation complexity?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to optimize the performance of some numpy code. The problem is, I'm just blindly replacing code with equivalent code, and profiling to compare the results.

Does numpy provide any resource describing the complexity/performance of its basic operations (either a theoretical analysis, or some practical rules of the thumb), for example

- basic operations (eg: sum, multiplication, exponentiation)
- different data types (eg: float vs complex)
- vectorization/broadcasting as function of the size of the matrix (eg: vectorizing beyond 2 dimensions seems to make performance worse than equivalent for-loop)

Comment: The complexity of the listed basic operation is `O(n)` with `n` the array size. The complexity is independent of the computed type (fixed-sized, unless you use object types which is discouraged). View based operations are done in constant time unless it involves a copy (this is often described in the doc). Things like vectorization do not change the complexity, only the performance. The performance of the operations is not reported as it is *implementation-dependent*. The best way to check that is to run it. *Performance is highly dependent of the target platform*. Otherwise, check the code.

Comment: "vectorizing beyond 2 dimensions seems to make performance worse than equivalent for-loop" - it depends on the operation and sizes of arrays.  As for resources - I would not expect to find what you want in numpy docs. Instead I would search there and elsewhere for some guidelines/"numpy tips" [like this one](https://shihchinw.github.io/2019/03/performance-tips-of-numpy-ndarray.html) (note I am not good enough to review this and say its 100% correct)